# Solution of equations of the form: $a^x+b^x+c=0$

Tags: roots

Is it possible to solve equations of the form: $a^x+b^x+c=0,\;abc\neq0$ with analytical methods; if so, how is this done?

Comment: What are you solving for?

Comment: You can't generally solve this analytically, however you can find "easy" solutions for special values of $a$ and $b$. Like $a$ = $b$ implies $a^x = -c/2$. Then using logarithm you are done.

Comment: @TimRatigan Solving for x.

Comment: Do these kinds of equations have a name?

Comment: There are infinitely-many solutions for $x=2$, and, of course, for $x=1$. Just a small data point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *a* is a power of *b*, or vice-versa, then the [transcendental equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) can be reduced to a polynomial one. Otherwise its solutions cannot even be expressed in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), so your only hope is to solve it by means of [numerical algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis).

Comment: I think you mean "If $b^\alpha=a$ for some $\alpha\in\Bbb Q$"

Comment: Yes, you're right. But even so, we must bear in mind that not all polynomial equations have analytical solutions, i.e., their roots are not expressible in radicals.